# Allocate extra space to process

Tags: c++

can I provide extra space to the process other than provided by the operating system.
Can extra  detachable memory be used for such purposes.

Comment: Yes, there are a number of ways of allocating memory, and your C/C++ library will take care of them for you. What are you wondering in particular?

Comment: Any OS with virtual memory (if you don't know what that means, your OS has it) will already use hard disks (and SSDs) to store data your process wants to have in memory which does not fit into RAM. That is, any process can use as much memory as the size of pointers permits. How much more space do you want?

Comment: You should specify what problem you are facing... If any.. I want to know in which contrast you are asking like you want to allocate memory to your program for some specific purpose, or you want to increase memory for processing or you want to use cpu registers...

Answer (score 2):

> can I provide extra space to the process other than provided by the
>   operating system.

No you cant, for every piece of memory you have to request your OS.
malloc(), new and other memory allocating functions and operator resolve as a system call that request OS for memory to be provided to the program.

Comment: +1 That's (almost always) right. Consider: the OS needs to reclaim memory when a process terminates, whether normally or due to some runtime error or other process killing it - that means the OS has to control and tracking the initial allocations, maintaining some sense of ownership. Even shared memory segments that are marked to persist after the process are still tracked by the OS, such that a subsequent process can close them (whether logically part of the application suite or an OS-standard management utility), and the OS can recycle them. (Bizarre hardware may have mem unknown to the OS.)

Answer (score 0):

Every process has a definite maximum memory space allocated to it, that depends on the machine architecture. On a 32-bit machine, the maximum addressable space is 2^32 bytes ~= 4GB. Hence a process should be able to address 4 GB of memory typically. But this space is divided into two parts, 1. Kernel Space and 2. Process Space. Kernel space is used for OS drivers etc while Process space is the space where your data can be allocated. Hence the memory available to you is just the Process space.

On a typical Windows XP machine, it is equally divided. i.e. 2 GB for process space (However, there are ways to modify this. For example, the /3G option). Any allocation beyond 2 GB gives a out of memory error.This process space becomes more when you move from a 32-bit application to a 64-bit application. This is one of the major incentives for moving to 64-bit applications.

So to answer your question, there is a maximum memory available to a process beyond which the OS denies memory allocations to the process.

Comment: Can i ask one thing. Why concept of paging and fragmentation is implemented in operating systems. I think to overcome this only and i think the concept you are talking about is used by processor for different low level processing and this is managed by operating system....

Comment: @BharatSharma:Lets say you have a 32-bit machine with 4 GB RAM. If I am running a single process, the process runs well as it has all the resources needed. Lets say I start one more process simultaneously,how would you run it? You would need extra 4GB of RAM.Not possible! So You would have to kick out some parts of first process to hard disk. The concept of paging and fragmentation are there for this reason.
Another simple argument as to why there cannot be more space is: Lets say I allow you to address more than 2^32 bytes. Where would you store the addresses? The pointers are just 32-bits!

Comment: But page size can be different and one more concept of segmentation is there.. So for a large application I think operating system can decide page or segment size. Of course there will be some maximum amount of memory which can be allocated to a process. But concept you are talking about is a low level processing concept which always be decided by operating system according to priority and several other parameters... So we must know in which contrast the question is asked...

Comment: @BharatSharma: I didn't get what you want to say. Could you please provide a link that explains the other segmentation concept? I am not sure how varying page size can give you more/less memory.

Comment: If you will look the concept of segmentation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation then you can understand that segments can have different size. I mean to say that number of pointers are fixed but memory pointed by them can have different size according to the requirement and that is decided by operating system. If you will look the concept of offset also then you can understand that pointers that contains the segment can be more than 2^32 because pointers for them is decided by offset.

Comment: @ChethanRavindranath: With PAE, a Windows process can definitely have more than 4GB allocated to it despite having 32 bits pointers. It's still managed by the OS, but it does provide a counterexample to your assumptions.

Comment: @MSalters: PAE requires having one more level of paging. User mode processes are not allowed to access the page tables. Only kernel can extend its address from PAE. Quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366796(v=vs.85).aspx - "PAE does not change the amount of virtual address space available to a process. Each process running in 32-bit Windows is still limited to a 4 GB virtual address space.".

Comment: @ChethanRavindranath: Half true. Processes can't do it directly, but they can via Address Windowing Extensions (AWE). The critical part is that Windows can _allocate_ memory to processes which is not _addressable_. Allocated non-addressable memory is not subject to the 4GB address limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are some obscure ways. E.g. if you would attach a Windows CE device to a Windows PC, the memory of that device could be accessed via the "RAPI" interface. The Windows OS wouldn't be aware of this device memory; this was handles via the ActiveSync service. It wasn't very quick memory, though.